# Query to annotation documentbody field is truncated to 2000 characters

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I am using CRM SDK for fetching the data from Annotation Table in Dynamics 365 CRM by implementing the following code.

```
                QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("annotation");
                query.Distinct = true;
                query.ColumnSet.AllColumns = true;
                query.Criteria.AddCondition("annotationid", 
                ConditionOperator.Equal, "2A5C8C6C-4155-E911-9114-005056BE2027");
                EntityCollection PartyEnt = CRMUtilities.RetrieveMultiple(query);
                Entity Annotation = new Entity();
                if (PartyEnt.Entities.Count > 0)
                {
                    Annotation = PartyEnt.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
                    string documentBody = Annotation.Attributes["documentbody"].ToString()
                }
```

I am successfully getting the data but with some limitation !

I fetched the data from annotation and save the base64 string in documentBody variable, the problem is that it only retrieved 2000 characters from documentBody attributes however in the database it has more than 2000 characters.

Help me out !

Is there is anything that needs to be set up in CRM to retrieve the full data ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `query.Distinct = true;` from your query.

Comment: @jasonscript It is a bug. I had the "pleasure" to deal with it a couple years ago, that's why I remember it so well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that directly,
You will first need to convert documentbody in Base64  and then convert that base64 into string
Here is sample code

```
Annotation = PartyEnt.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
  //converting document body content to bytes              
byte[] fileinByte= Convert.FromBase64String(Annotation.Attributes["documentbody"].ToString());

//Converting to String
string fileContentinString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileinByte);
```